# Some devices deliberately throttle charging input?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

## Powerbank

I have an 50Wh “Hama Pipe” powerbank with 21W output power (2×2.1A ports OR 2.4A+1.8A), which would equal 4.2A at 5V in total, minus resistance.

But the **input power** is only 2.5W, which equals 0.5A at 5V. *(no typo, see http://www.hama.com/00137422/hama-power-pack-pipe-13000-mah-weiss-grau)*

Is that a technical limitation? The powerbank does not produce any heat during charge, so it is probably an *easily bypassable** limitation of the charging IC of the powerbank.

I have a different powerbank with 10W of input power, which produces heat.

**Is that 2W limitation technical? Can it be bypassed?**

## Smartphone

My smartphone supports fast charging (9V 1.7A), but when I connect it using 5V, it does not take 3A (charger has 20W maximum output), not 2A but only 1.2A. I should build a power step-up transformer out if hardware modules.

It is not because of the resistance in the long cable. Short cables aloow 5V 1.3A. **The USB multimeter shows 5.26V 1.21A for the long cable.**

### It is because the **charging controller refuses to take all available power.**

How can I manually overthrottle the charging IC?

Comment: It doesn't have to "throttle" the input, it just draws what it was designed to draw. It doesn't care that more is available than it needs.

Comment: Yes, devices do "throttle the input", in some sense. Try to search the EE site for terms "charger signature". Think of the problem: how your device may know that your powerbank can do 4 A?

Answer (score 1):

*How can I manually overthrottle the charging IC?*

You can't and you should not.

The charging current of the powerbank is a technical limitation due to the **design choices** made by the manufacturer.

Charging over USB can be made faster **but** more complex and/or more expensive electronics might be needed.

*I should build a power step-up transformer out if hardware modules.*

Why? It will not work and will very likely **damage** your phone.

You might think that you simply need a higher voltage to make the devices charge faster. It is not that simple. USB is 5 V **unless** the power adapter and the device "talk" to each other and both decide that a higher voltage is OK. That's needed to prevent a power supply to feed 12 V over USB to a phone that is only designed for charging with 5 V over USB.

Comment: My phone can charge with 9V, so I can transform 5v to 9V.

Comment: Thanks, nevertheless. Unable to upvote due to insufficient reputation points.

Comment: *My phone can charge with 9V, so I can transform 5v to 9V* You still don't get it. You cannot just feed 9 V to the phone because the phone expects a certain **protocoll** to be followed, example: Qualcomm quickcharge. If you "just" apply 9 V the phone might be damaged and might not even charge any faster. To charge efficiently at 9V or more a DCDC converter might be needed which might not be active in the "5 V" mode. But sure, ignore my advice and try it but don't complain to me that I didn't warn you when you break your phone.

Comment: I charged my phone often using a _just-feed_ 7V charger, without any problems. Nothing happened. My old test phone refuses to accept *any* charge above 6.4V. The charging IC can already control everything. But yes, I will take care, and not _just feed_ 9V. However, what happens, if that protocol is not followed?

Comment: *However, what happens, if that protocol is not followed?* it is written in my comment above. What happens depends on the design of the charging circuit in the phone. When you apply more than 5 V without the proper charger then you rely on what the manufacturer did to handle that situation. The charging circuit could be damaged and/or overheat. It will very likely not charge your phone any faster. Why not simply fast charge in the way it is intended to be used: by using the charger which is supplied with the phone.